# Let Ω be the set of all nonnegative integers and S the class of all subsets of Ω. In the given cases does P define a probability on (Ω,S)?

Tags: probability

For $A ∈ S$, let $P(A) = \begin{cases}
    1,& \text{if } A  \text{ has a finite number of elements}\\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$.

Comment: No since $P(\Omega) = 0$.

Comment: And if you reverse the $1$ and $0$ then it is still not a probability because of the issue with countable unions

Comment: I understand that Ω is a guaranteed event that's why it's probability can't be zero. But why not exactly another way around? Could you suggest me some good read about it?